# Search Box not working

Tags: c#, xampp

When I type in my search box my Data grid view doesn't show the data that i typed in even though its in the database. This is my codes for the search box

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        con = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblregister where FirstName like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource =ds;
```

Comment: BTW. What is I put `'; drop database; ` in the textbox?

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code, one of them being assigning `con` twice. You also never close it.

Comment: You are using `ds` to populating datagridview but `ds` is nowhere being populated. The dataset `dt` and datatable `ds` not connected to each other.

Comment: Change `adapt.Fill(dt);` to `adapt.Fill(ds);` and remove `DataSet dt = new DataSet();`. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks guys you helped me a lot 